# How to use (not install) Google Web Starter Kit?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-web-starter-kit

I created my website using Bootstrap, but now I'd like to move it to Google Web Starter Kit (GWSK).
I installed as explained everywhere on internet, and everything works.

However, now I'm not sure what to do now. First I'm not sure why there is a index.html and a basic.html. Is one page used in one situation and the other in another one ? Or is it just 2 different styles ?

Also, now I'm not sure what to do. If I look at GWSK Visual Guide documentation they said to use grids like that: g-medium--half for example, but in the index.html they use MDL (mdl-layout, etc...).

Which one should I use ?
What bothering me is, you can find lots of tutorial (often it's the same on different website) to tell you how to install it, but I couldn't find one that helps me to use it. Maybe I missed it, but if it's the case, could you please point me to it ?

I found this one [http://google.github.io/web-starter-kit/hello-world/styleguide.html](http://google.github.io/web-starter-kit/hello-world/styleguide.htm) but it's seems the index.html coming as an example is not using that style.

If some can help me, that would be awesome.
Thank you.

Comment: Someone ? Any idea ?